# Spark: apply sliding() to each row without UDF

Tags: scala, apache-spark, apache-spark-sql

I have a Dataframe with several columns. The i-th column contains strings. I want to apply the string `sliding(n)` function to each string in the column. Is there a way to do so without using user-defined functions?

Example:
My dataframe is

```
var df = Seq((0, "hello"), (1, "hola")).toDF("id", "text")
```

I want to apply the `sliding(3)` function to each element of column `"text"` to obtain a dataframe corresponding to

```
Seq(
    (0, ("hel", "ell", "llo"))
    (1, ("hol", "ola"))
)
```

How can I do this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For spark version >= 2.4.0, this can be done using the inbuilt functions [`array_repeat`](https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/api/sql/index.html#array_repeat), [`transform`](https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/api/sql/index.html#transform) and `substring`.

```
import org.apache.spark.sql.functions.{array_repeat, transform, substring}

//Repeat the array `n` times
val repeated_df = df.withColumn("tmp",array_repeat($"text",length($"text")-3+1))
//Get the slices with transform higher order function
val res = repeated_df.withColumn("str_slices",
                                 expr("transform(tmp,(x,i) -> substring(x from i+1 for 3))")
                                )
//res.show()
+---+-----+---------------------+---------------+
|id |text |tmp                  |str_slices     |
+---+-----+---------------------+---------------+
|0  |hello|[hello, hello, hello]|[hel, ell, llo]|
|1  |hola |[hola, hola]         |[hol, ola]     |
+---+-----+---------------------+---------------+
```

Comment: Thank you so much! What if now I wanted to apply a function (e.g. hash()) to each of the substring in the str_slices column?